# in a sub query im trying to select from a table that was defined in outer query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi im getting "Error Code: 1146. Table 'sakila.t' doesn't exist" on the next sql code.

```
select distinct address.address
  from (
         select inventory.store_id, 
                count(inventory.inventory_id) as num_of_items
                from inventory
                group by inventory.store_id
       ) as T,
       address,
       store,
 where T.num_of_items <= all (select num_of_items from T)
   and store.store_id = T.store_id 
   and store.address_id = address.address_id
```

*From a comment* This is supposed to return the address of the store that has the smallest number of items in its inventory.

I think its because im trying to get information from T in the sub query, and T is a variable and isnt defined in sakila database. is it the problem? if yes why? if not, please tell me what is the problem with the code. thanks.

Comment: There's got to be a better way to write this.  I think the reason it hasn't been touched in 45 minutes is that the SQL is so obtuse that nobody can easily figure out what you're trying to do.  Have you tried to rewrite it with JOINS?

Comment: how can I write it with joins? I have to use the "all" keyword in where, do I?

Comment: Can you start by explaining what this query is supposed to do, conceptually?

Comment: Return the address of the store that has the smallest number of items in its inventory.

Comment: cool, that helps.  Can you show your tables' schemas?  What would be best is an SQLFiddle with `CREATE TABLE ...` statements that create the relevant parts of the tables.

Comment: Im not allowed to use create. I really want to understand what am I doing wrong. Is it a problem to select from a table that was defined in outer query ?

Comment: You don't need to create, you need to SHOW CREATE so we can see what your tables look like.  We don't understand what you're doing wrong because we don't know what your tables look like.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html .. is this good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this kind of SQL query to work, you need to break down the task.

First, you're trying to figure out how many items each store contains.  This is easy, and you have it right, I think.

```
     select inventory.store_id, 
            count(inventory.inventory_id) as num_of_items
       from inventory
      group by inventory.store_id
```

Next, you want to figure out which store has the fewest number of items. You do that like this.

```
     select inventory.store_id, 
            count(inventory.inventory_id) as num_of_items
       from inventory
       group by inventory.store_id
       order by count(inventory.inventory_id) ASC
       limit 1
```

Next, you nest this inside a query which finds the data describing the stores.

```
select address.address
  from (
       select inventory.store_id, 
              count(inventory.inventory_id) as num_of_items
         from inventory
         group by inventory.store_id
         order by count(inventory.inventory_id)
         limit 1
       ) as T
  join store on T.store_id = store.store_id
  join address on store.address_id = address.address_id
```

And that's the result you need. The trick here is to use the aggregate subquery (`count() ... order by ... limit 1) to find the particular item you need, then to use a bunch of`join` clauses to gather together the data you need to display about the item you found.

When you debug and troubleshoot this kind of thing, you start with the simplest query, and build your query up set by step.

Comment: Hi, first of all - thank you for the detailed answer. But I really want to understand whats wrong with the way I did it, to avoid mistakes in the future.